# Cannot get TGMHeatmap to work

Tags: gmlib

We can't see how TGMHeatmap works, even using MegaDemo and heapmap.csv. The properties we set for TGMHeatmap are the same as for MageDemo (except language), we do this in FormCreate:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DefLat := 52.189746;
  DefLng := -2.215933;
  GMMap1.RequiredProp.Center.Lat := DefLat;
  GMMap1.RequiredProp.Center.Lng := DefLng;
  GMMap1.Active := True;
  GMHeatmap.LoadFromCSV(0, 1, 'C:\Temp\svhscusts.csv', ',', True, True);
end;
```

and this in a button for displaying the Heatmap

```
procedure TForm1.BHeatmapClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  GMMap1.SetCenter(52.189746, -2.215933);
  GMMap1.RequiredProp.Zoom := 13;
  GMHeatmap.Show := not GMHeatmap.Show;
end;
```

The format of the data file is (each on one line)

52.00240,-2.11490
52.00240,-2.11490
52.00200,-2.11400
52.00200,-2.11400
52.00400,-2.10950
52.00400,-2.10950
52.00400,-2.10950

Since MegaDemo does not [appear to] work as expected, perhaps using/updating MegaDemo would be the easiest way of explaining what isn't working (or what we are not doing correctly).

Excellent software, incidentally. If Google would reduce it's licence fees for small customers, we could use it properly

Comment: I don't understand you. MegaDemo not working properly or you don't know how TGMHeapMap work? If you don't know how work TGMHeapMap, please, read this article in [my blog](http://www.cadetill.com/cosas-del-twebbrowser) (in spanish, but you can translate it if you don't understand it).

Comment: We knew nothing about FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION, now we do (thanks to you). Maybe a mention of this in the code for MegaDemo? Now all working fine.

Comment: into main constructor I have a call to ControlIEVersion Method. Yes, no comments about this, I can put it :)